# min and max height expression tree

Tags: binary-tree, expression-trees

When constructing an expression tree with n binary operations, which maximum and minimum height can I expect? I would be very thankful if someone has a general formula, because I couldn't find one and I also wasn't able to find a schema in the examples I worked with.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have n operations. Naturally, the maximum height is n + 1, on the first level you see the root operation, on the last level you see value leafs and on all other levels you see an operation node and a value leaf. The minimum depth (if your operations always "cut" the expression in the middle) is of ceil(log(2, 2 * n + 1)).